# Replacing Table Body via Javascript based on parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I have several products I want to create **A** HTML/JS form for. (I have them currently all on their own individual forms working fine, however I would rather use a "Master" form.)

The form needs to display a table with different rows depending on which product it is.

I have seen the JavaScript for creating tables dynamically with making a table object and loading up the items as arrays but I do not think that will work since I need to run functions during the onchange events of the inputs in the cells.

Is there a way to have multiple table bodies built and switch them?

Here is a mock up picture to show how two different product tables may appear for clarification.

[image: This is an example of how the different products table could appear, green indicated inputs]

```
<script> window.onload = "addTable()" </script>

function addTable() {

var base5Table = [{
        "description": "Visual",
        input1: true,
        "specification": "Pass/Fail",
        input2: false,
        input3: false,
        input4: true,
        "result": "Pass",
        input5: true
    },
    {
        "description": "Rate",
        input1: true,
        "specification": "≥ 200 ",
        input2: true,
        input3: true,
        input4: true,
        "result": "Pass",
        input5: true
    }
];
var allRows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < base5Table.length; i++) {
    var row = "<tr>" + "<td>" + base5Table[i].description + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + base5Table[i].input + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + base5Table[i].specification + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + base5Table[i].input2 + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + base5Table[i].input3 + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + base5Table[i].input4 + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + base5Table[i].result + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + base5Table[i].input5 + "</td>" + "</tr>";

        allRows.push(row);
}
document.querySelector('table').innerHTML = allRows.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Columns are the same for every row?

Comment: That is correct, there are 8 columns that remain the same across all products.

Comment: It's arguably better to just use `window.onload = addTable;` instead of setting `onload` to a string.

Comment: @Mike I thought that was proper syntax for the JS/HTML environment? [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) w3Schools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is create an object with all of the products' info and then create table rows for each product.

```
var products = [{'name':'product1','price':10,'color':'red'},
                {'name':'product2','price':15,'color':'blue'},
                {'name':'product3','price':20,'color':'green'}
               ];
//save all rows here
var allRows = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
   var row = '<tr>'+'<td>'+products[i].name+'</td>'+
             '<td>'+products[i].price+'</td>'+
             '<td>'+products[i].color+'</td>'+'</tr>';
   allRows.push(row);
}
//append all rows to page
document.querySelector('table').innerHTML = allRows.join(' ');
```

**EDIT**

This code will do everything that you want, including inserting the input elements. You need the script to create the input elements. So I crated a function that does just that called `createInput()`.

```js
addTable();

function addTable() {

var base5Table = [{
        "description": "Visual",
        input1: true,
        "specification": "Pass/Fail",
        input2: false,
        input3: false,
        input4: true,
        "result": "Pass",
        input5: true
    },
    {
        "description": "Rate",
        input1: true,
        "specification": "≥ 200 ",
        input2: true,
        input3: true,
        input4: true,
        "result": "Pass",
        input5: true
    }
];
var allRows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < base5Table.length; i++) {
    var row = "<tr>" + "<td>" + base5Table[i].description + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + createInput(base5Table[i].input1) + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + base5Table[i].specification + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + base5Table[i].input2 + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + base5Table[i].input3 + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + base5Table[i].input4 + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + base5Table[i].result + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + base5Table[i].input5 + "</td>" + "</tr>";

        allRows.push(row);
}
document.querySelector('table').innerHTML = allRows.join(" ");
}

//this function will return an input element if true
function createInput(val){
 var opt = {
   true: function(){
     var i = '<input type="text" />';
      return i;
    },
    false: function(){
     return
    }
  };
  return opt[val]();
}
```

```html
<table>

</table>
```

Comment: I do not believe this will work since I only want to show the 1 products rows at a time. I could probably modify it to only spit out rows belonging to a certain name, however using a for loop to create the tds won't allow for the inclusion of inputs would it?

Comment: @TheAngryAuditor in the loop, you can include any element you'd like, including `input` elements. You said you want to show 1 product at a time. How though? Will the user select the product?

Comment: That is also why I think I cannot use a loop based approach, if you see in the sample not every TD has an input. The user will select the product via a dropdown menu. The part I can't figure out is once the selection is checked, how do I display the appropriate table.

Comment: @TheAngryAuditor in the comments you stated that the columns are the same for every row. If that's true, then you can design the structure once and have it print out for each product.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what the other poster was asking in regards to the columns being the same. I meant that every product's table will consist of 8 columns. The actual contents of the cells in the columns will differ. Most of the cells will require user input, while others will have plain text.

Comment: @TheAngryAuditor you can state that in the products object: `{name:'p1',color:'red',price:10,input:true},{name:'p2',color:'blue',price:20,input:false}`

Comment: @JosanIracherta are you able to place multiple inputs with input:true or is it just like one per td? Would {name:'2',input:true, input:true) result in 2 inputs? I don't see this on the ol' google.

Comment: @TheAngryAuditor you can place as many inputs as you would like, you would just have to structure your object that way. For example, let's say you had two inputs in total, but one product had 2 inputs and the other product had one, you could structure the object like so: `{name:'p1',input1:true,input2:true},{name:'p2',input1:false,input2:true}`

Comment: Iracherta I have tried modifying your suggested layout to fit my variables and place it inside of an addTable function, which gets called by window.onload however I must have done something wrong as it does not display the table.

Comment: I had a few typos but still cannot seem to get it to work, the code is appended to the initial post.

Comment: @TheAngryAuditor the script works but you might be referring to the part where you want it to create `input` elements. You took my code literally. In the code, you're supposed to tell it to create the input elements.

Comment: @ Josan Thank you, I am unfamiliar with HTML/JavaScript syntax past the basic stuff, so I interpreted that as literal. That would explain why I was unable to find that syntax when Googling. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have ids you can just add an event listener for the inputs assuming you give them an ID.

```
function MyFunction() {
     // DO Stuff
}
// JS Code to make your table
// ...

// Add Event Listener for input
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("onchange", MyFunction);
```

Comment: This is helpful information, thank you. But that still leaves me with inputs needing to be created. Can inputs be a part of an array?

Comment: Updated answer - Mike McCaughan : You are correct.  The parameter is the name of the function without the parenthesis characters